# Can't get page content using Python Requests on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, python-requests

I have been trying to get Option Chain data from the NSE site using python-requests. I am able to get the data successfully on a local machine but when I run the same script on AWS EC2 Linux instance, it neither gives me an error nor the result. can anyone please help? I have placed a screenshot below:

import requests

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"

headers = {'user-agent': 'Chrome/88.0.4324.182',"accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8", "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"}

try:

page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

except Exception as e:

print(e)

print(page.text)

[Code running on local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QxaL.png)

[When I run the same script on AWS EC2 Linux instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdrnr.png)

Comment: post your code rather than images

Comment: Can you try curl on the EC2 to see if the issue is with calling the url from ec2 (in which case your vpc / Security groups are blocking external url's) or if the issue is with python code. Also, I second @JatinMehrotra's comment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have updated original post with code. sorry for the delayed response. @Durja, i run "curl https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY" on EC2 terminal and it said "Access Denied, you do not have permission to access '.......'  on this server. So it's the issue AWS EC2 Security, Could you please guide me on how to get the  required access?

Comment: @ankitkhokhar - Review the security groups for your EC2 and check the inbound and outbound traffic settings. I am not sure if I can be of help if you're working in an enterprise setting.

Comment: @Durja, I am using "t2 micro" free tier of AWS EC2 Linux instance, inbound had two rule allowing SSH connection from all source and one outbound rule allowing "all". I tried adding HTTP, HTTPs and also "All" inside inbound rule but still the same permission denied error. then i tried removing all condition from inbound and outbound rule, but that also didn't work.

Comment: Hi @ankitkhokhar any lead or solution on the above issue, am facing exact same issues, plz share your guidelines

Comment: HI, I am facing same issue. I was facing same issue on server curl call to NSE option chain. but later on I thought to create local kind of environment so I create amazon workspace linux 2. but still getting same error from workspace as well.